# How to block websites from AD DC Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

**How to block websites from Active Directory Domain Controller Windows Server 2012**

request form our company.. to block YouTube.com from Domain controller ( which is windows server 2012) from morning 9am to evening 5pm.

how can i achieve this requirement. i saw some online blogs which is showing group policy settings but they just blocks the website with GPO. what i want is to block website for a specific time (Like morning 9 am to evening 5pm)  not all the time....

please help me

Answer (score 1):

This can be achived with an ISA server or Forefront TMG (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e05aecbc-d0eb-4e0f-a5db-8f236995bccd&displaylang=en) or any other proxy solution like SQUID(it's free http://www.squid-cache.org)

Comment: is it possible to block for time base like  morning 9am to evening 5pm.

Comment: @San In a word, no. AD has no interaction with the users browsing experience, web traffic is directed through your proxy if you have one, then your gateway and so it is at these points you would need to filter the traffic. AD is used to authenticate users, validate the users access rights for resources and can be used to prevent the user accessing the internet at all by blocking access to browsing applications, or directing to a non-existant proxy, but it cannot filter sites.

Answer (score 0):

"AD has no interaction with the users browsing experience, web traffic is directed through your proxy if you have one, then your gateway and so it is at these points you would need to filter the traffic."
I wouldnt agree. You can restrict websites via DNS (but im not sure about time period thing though). Set new DNS zone in DNS manager, and call it, for example Facebook.com. Then, right click on zone, and click on New Host (AAAA), and set Facebook to imaginary ip address such as 0.0.0.0, and voila. Your clients won't be able to connect to Facebook.com

Comment: But they will be able to connect to facebook via facebook ip adress :D